# Displaying a Modal dialog box after successful form submission

Tags: model-view-controller, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, umbraco

I for the life of me cant figure out how to display a modal pop up dialog box after the form has been submitted. The dialog box should only appear after i receive a ViewBag value from the controller and then we can take it from there but i just can`t get the modal box to pop up and the page just navigates to my redirected page. I am also using Umbraco Surface controller instead of the usual MVC controller class.

I have tried to use ViewBags and data-toggle with data-target to modal but to no avail. Still can`t get modal to pop up.

**View**

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal" />
```

**Modal**

```
 @if (ViewBag.Status != null)
    {
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Successfully Registered</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    Congratulations!!! you have been registered to our website. You will recieve an email for confirmation.

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='/';">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(RegistrationModel model)
    {


        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        if (ModelState.IsValid) { 


            // Get the details and save it to model
            RegisterUser(model);
            TempData["ContactSuccess"] = true;
            //SendEmail(model);
            // TempData["Success"] = true;
            ViewBag.Status = "Success";
            return RedirectToUmbracoPage(1144);
            // return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();


        }
        return RedirectToUmbracoPage(1146);


        //return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
```

My Expected result would just be to show the modal pop up and stop the redirection. I know i would need to change the returntoumbracopage return but i just need some help on this.

Comment: The RedirectTo... methods redirect the browser so you lose the ViewBag. Try with `return CurrentUmbracoPage()`;

Comment: Cool. Let me try with currentbracopage , will update you if it works

Comment: hmmm. Seem to get the below error when i do this:   Can only use UmbracoPageResult in the context of an Http POST when using a SurfaceController form

Comment: You have to use an BeginUmbracoForm to stay in the Umbraco context. (`@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm(){}`) )https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/forms#using-beginumbracoform

Comment: Hi Mario, That is also a good option but i have a specific Multi form setup in the application as per client`s request and i need to follow that. I tried using Umbraco forms but sadly it did not work out as per the client requirements so yeah i was push into using the <Forms> tag. The problem was that the fieldsets i am using in the form are not displayed page wise when i use Umbraco forms for some reason.

Comment: That's not the Umbraco Forms plugin, that's the way you have to create a form in the frontend so it submits to a SurfaceController keeping the Umbraco context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying your controller logic I would set the success state in a session. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8

Alternatively, it would be a better approach to post the data using Ajax and returning a JSON model representing the state of the form submission and updating the page accordingly.

Comment: Good option. Instead of ViewBag. Let me see if it works and i will let you know :)

Comment: Will you are life saver, sessions worked brilliantly, i am sorry i cant post the answer due to an answer ban . I will answer it once the ban is lifted. So i ended up setting a session value and using it on the Home page and then using ajax set the session to empty so it`s not called again.